# Annoying top margin with recent versions of tcolorbox and amsthm

Tags: spacing, pdftex, tcolorbox, amsthm, parskip

After installing a fresh TeXLive (2023), I noticed an annoying issue with margins when using amsthm environments inside tcolorboxes. On the left, the (expected) result I got before updating, on the right, the one produced by the fresh TeXLive 2023 install.

[image: Annoying margin in tcolorbox]

As you can see, there's now some vertical space added before the "theorem"/"proof" keyword (it's more obvious in the second case, but both exhibit a similar issue), and I can't find where it comes from (except it's somehow related to a non-null parskip) or how I can get rid of it.

Here is the MWE producing the results above (on a 2023 TeXLive vs a previous install):

```
\documentclass {article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,theorems,breakable}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlength{\parskip}{1.2ex plus 0.6ex minus 0.2ex}

\tcolorboxenvironment{proof}{blanker,before skip=4mm plus 1mm minus 1mm,after=\par,parbox=false,breakable,
                             left=2mm,borderline west={0.6mm}{0pt}{black}}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\tcolorboxenvironment{thm}{breakable,before skip=4mm plus 1mm minus 1mm,after=\par,parbox=false,
                           boxrule=0pt,left=1mm,right=1mm,top=1mm,bottom=1mm,enhanced jigsaw}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1][1-3]
\begin{thm} \lipsum[2][1-3] \end{thm}
\lipsum[3][1-3]
\begin{proof} \lipsum[4][1-3] \end{proof}
\lipsum[5][1-3]
\end{document}
```

I'd gladly take any suggestion that can help me find a solution before it turns me crazy :)

Comment: it is probably due to this issue https://github.com/T-F-S/tcolorbox/issues/199

Comment: Possibly indeed, i'll investigate, thanks. I found bug reports on the issue, like https://github.com/T-F-S/tcolorbox/issues/122 (it's getting worse, amsthm wasn't affected, but it is now). But it doesn't help much, my current workaround consists in using a parbox and resetting manually the parskip in *all* theorem environments (hooks on env/begin don't work, too early), which is quite awful :(

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the key `parbox=false` in both of your definitions, the output is as expected.

[image]

```
\documentclass {article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,theorems,breakable}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlength{\parskip}{1.2ex plus 0.6ex minus 0.2ex}

\tcolorboxenvironment{proof}{blanker,before skip=4mm plus 1mm minus 1mm,after=\par,breakable,
                             left=2mm,borderline west={0.6mm}{0pt}{black}}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\tcolorboxenvironment{thm}{breakable,before skip=4mm plus 1mm minus 1mm,after=\par,
                           boxrule=0pt,left=1mm,right=1mm,top=1mm,bottom=1mm,enhanced jigsaw}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1][1-3]
\begin{thm} \lipsum[2][1-3] \end{thm}
\lipsum[3][1-3]
\begin{proof} \lipsum[4][1-3] \end{proof}
\lipsum[5][1-3]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, it does indeed, but unless I'm mistaken, it's because it creates a box for the tcolorbox where parskip is 0. So that eliminates the gap at the beginning, but also the space between paragraphs inside the boxes, which I want to keep.

I should have used two paragraphs in each box for clarity.

But in any case, many thanks for the suggestion!